# PHP script to upload different files to different servers

Tags: php, process, batch-file, ftp

is there some PHP script or a way to automatically batch upload various files to remote FTP servers.

Let me give you an example, I have a folder structure like this, which includes files.

```
../domain1.com/
../domain2.com/
../domain3.com/
```

Where each domain folder has different FTP login details to remote server.

Comment: Don't need PHP, a couple lines of shell would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write one, it's quite simple thanks to [PHP's FTP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php).

Here is a script tutorial that uploads files to an FTP server, just add an [array of FTP servers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to the script and loop through with a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and your good:

http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/ftp-example.htm

Your array of FTP servers may look something like ...

```
Array =>
  [0] => Array
     [folder] => 'domain1.com',
     [ftp_server] => 'ftp.thisisdomain1.com',
     [ftp_user] => 'user',
     [ftp_pass] => 'pass',
   [1] => Array
     [folder] => 'domain2.com',
     [ftp_server] => 'ftp.thisisdomain2.com',
     [ftp_user] => 'user2',
     [ftp_pass'] => 'pass2',
```

Etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write it yourself ;). Its quite easy. PHP has a library for [FTP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php). Together with [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), you could create a nice script that will take care of this.